# Saving tabular, spreadsheet-like data in a relational database?

Tags: database, database-design, persistence

I'm hoping this question isn't too broad or too prone to opinionated answers, since I could really use some pointers.

I'm trying to come up with a way to persist tabular, spreadsheet-like<sup>1</sup>, data in a backend. Since the data could very well end up being rather fuzzy (not easily identifiable as being identical, even though the user may have intended it to be), I'm having doubts about persisting it in a relational SQL database.

Users will be able to create multiple tables of this kind:

```
+====================================================+
| category                                           |
+==============================+==========+==========+
| item                         |  type A  |  type B  |
+==============================+==========+==========+
| name                         |    value |    value |
+------------------------------+----------+----------+
| name                         |    value |    value |
+------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

The data will merely be used for representational purposes, to give an overview of categorized items and there respective type values. No relational business logic between cell-data will be implemented.

Per table, users will be able to define a certain custom amount of `type` columns. Furthermore, there will not be too many constraints on the permitted cell data, except for the `value` cells, which will be numeric<sup>2</sup>. Lastly, users will also be able to migrate `item` rows and `type` columns between tables.

Originally, my idea was to persist this in a relational SQL database, which, simplified, pretty much comes down to this:

```
category
------
id            PK
name

item
------
id            PK
category_id   FK category(id)
name
sortOrder

type
------
id            PK
category_id   FK category(id)
name
sortOrder

item_type_value
------
id            PK
item_id       FK item(id)
type_id       FK type(id)
value
```

The main reasons I'm having starting to have doubts about persisting this in a relational database is that even though a user may intend `type A` in one table to mean the same as `type-a` in some other table, I'll never be certain. And since I don't want to restrict the user too much (nor do I want to burden myself with too complicated an interface, like letting users first define a `type`, which they can *then* select from a drop-down, for instance, or ask whether they intended `"type-a"` to mean the same as `"type A"`), I doubt this lends itself particularly well for a relational setup, other than perhaps defining relations about which cells belongs to which tables, etc.

If one is to assume aforementioned lenient constraints, does it make sense to look for an alternative persistent storage mechanisms than a relational SQL database?

If so, could you suggest a particularly well-suited persistence mechanism for this type of data? NoSQL or XML, perhaps?

---

<sup>1) Perhaps spreadsheet-like is a bit misleading; it will simply be tables where users will be able to insert scalar values (strings and/or numbers) in cells. Nothing more; no formulas, calculations, etc. "Spreadsheet-like" pertains to the fact that users will be able to edit the cell-data inline. That's where the similarity basically ends.</sup>

<sup>2) The numeric constraint isn't actually that important either. It's predominantly mentioned to give a little bit of context.</sup>

Comment: If find your relation OK as long as all values are of the same type and s long as there won't be a "type c" which violates the [1st normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Note: you should not make your code and database design ready for a future that may never come and you should obey database normalization. A document oriented database might be an alternative if the model should be flexible/changable.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I'm a bit confused about "as long as there won't be a type c". My current relational database design allows for this with the table `type`, does it not? Would you mind expanding on what you meant? If a user wants to add a new `type` "type c" to a `category` table (the user interface table, not the database table), my current database design allows for this by inserting into `type` the values `( null, category_id, "type c", sortOrder )`.

Comment: How do you think that using an alternative persistence technology will resolve your data quality & cleansing problem?

Comment: You design allows a type c, yes. But continue reading my note: if type c actually consists of two values or another type then you might get into trouble. You have do define a column type (for `item_type_value.value`), e.g. `integer`: you can't add "type c" of type `varchar`. If you design it for column type `varchar`, then 1) storing numbers as would be unoptimized 2) adding a 3rd type that stores more complex data may violate the 1st NF.

Comment: @ErikEidt Good question. I just thought that, since this data quality aspect is rather lenient, the relational aspect would become pretty much irrelevant here, thereby perhaps allowing for a much simpler storage mechanism. Do you think that makes sense?

Comment: @try-catch-finally Ah, I see what you mean now, yes! Perhaps your concerns give even more credence to ditching RDBMS, in this particular case. Would you agree?

Comment: No, I think the concerns are orthogonal: data quality issues exists across the board independent of technologies.  I'd suggest investing in a solution for that more directly.  For example, addresses usually get verified by a post office service, so that spelling differences (2nd vs. Second, ST vs. Street, etc..) are made canonical.  This wholly independent of technological choice in persistence.

Comment: @ErikEidt The thing is: in this regard, my application will actually be similar to a speadsheet, in that the user is pretty much free to enter anything they like; save for perhaps the numeric `value` constraint, the application will not be responsible to verify data consistency/integrity. It's basically up to the user to verify consistency, where they intend any to be. I guess I could rephrase my question to: how does an web application like Google Sheets persist a spreadsheet?